# errno 13 _ Permission denied: ´/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

When running a sail up to install Laravel with docker, I get the following error:

```
> #0 129.7 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-310.pyc.139841984059904'dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
> #0 129.7  installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
> #0 129.8 Errors were encountered while processing:
> #0 129.8  python3.10-minimal
> #0 129.8 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I try to modify the permissions on the group in the path usr/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/ but not limited.

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: it throws me the same error

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with Ubuntu and Docker, installed via Snap.

To resolve the problem, I removed it using the command `sudo snap remove docker`.

After that, I followed the instructions in the official Docker tutorial for Ubuntu, which can be found at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/. The tutorial guided me through a successful reinstallation of Docker, and now everything is working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

0

In my case, the following sequence of actions helped:

1. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
2. `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. `sudo systemctl restart docker.socket docker.service`
4. `docker rm -f <container id>` // remove all containers which can cause your problem
5. Retry docker container building

Comment: When you copy verbatim [another contribution of yours](https://askubuntu.com/a/1482634), at least take the time to properly remove the irrelevant parts (the 0 at the start)... Thanks!